# Conversion of JSON to XML errors out when I try to write to file

Tags: python, json, pandas, xml

I am in the process of doing a conversion of JSON to XML using Python.

I'm giving a presentation of how by starting with one file, CSV, you can convert it through multiple formats in a chain. So, CSV to JSON, that JSON to XML, XML to the next file type in the chain, etc, back to CSV.

I obtained a public domain CSV file from Kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/canggih/anime-data-score-staff-synopsis-and-genre), then converted it to JSON.

From JSON, I am trying to convert to XML and write to an outfile.

I converted the CSV to JSON using this (no formatting, just a straight conversion):

```
#This should convert CSV to JSON
import json, os
import pandas as pd
import csv

df = pd.read_csv('dataanime.csv')

df.to_json(r'sassyg_data_Anime.json')
```

Then, I created my JSON to XML file:

```
#With help from instructor and CodeSpeedy
#https://www.codespeedy.com/how-to-convert-json-to-xml-using-python/

#Import libraries
import json as j
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

#load in the json file
with open("sassyg_data_Anime.json") as json_file_format:
    d = j.load(json_file_format)

#create the main container element for the entire XML file
r = et.Element("Work")

#creates the subelements for each part of the json file
et.SubElement(r,"Title").text = d["Title"]
et.SubElement(r,"Type").text = d["Type"]
et.SubElement(r,"Episodes").text = d["Episodes"]
et.SubElement(r,"Status").text = d["Status"]
et.SubElement(r,"Start airing").text = str(d["Start airing"])
et.SubElement(r,"End airing").text = str(d["End airing"])
et.SubElement(r,"Starting season").text = d["Starting season"]
et.SubElement(r,"Broadcast time").text = d["Broadcast time"]
et.SubElement(r,"Producers").text = d["Producers"]
et.SubElement(r,"Licensors").text = d["Licensors"]
et.SubElement(r,"Studios").text = d["Studios"]
et.SubElement(r,"Sources").text = d["Sources"]
et.SubElement(r,"Genres").text = d["Genres"]
et.SubElement(r,"Duration").text = str(d["Duration"])
et.SubElement(r,"Rating").text = d["Rating"]
et.SubElement(r,"Score").text = str(d["Score"])
et.SubElement(r,"Scored by").text = str(d["Scored by"])
et.SubElement(r,"Members").text = str(d["Members"])
et.SubElement(r,"Favorites").text = str(d["Favorites"])
et.SubElement(r,"Description").text = d["Description"]

#create the element tree/info for the write file
a = et.ElementTree(r)

#ERROR ERROR
#structure the output for xml via tostring rather than str
#Cannot write an ElementTree to file, errors out
#This was one solution I came up with, still errors out
a_xml_str = et.tostring(a)
print(a_xml_str)

#This might error out as well, I can't get the program to get to this point
#write file it should go to
outfile = open("json_to_xml.xml", 'w', encoding='utf-8')
outfile.write(a_xml_str)
outfile.close()
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Data_Int_Final\Gardner_json_to_xml\convert_json_to_xml.py", line 44, in <module>
    a_xml_str = et.tostring(a)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1109, in tostring
    ElementTree(element).write(stream, encoding,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 748, in write
    serialize(write, self._root, qnames, namespaces,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 873, in _serialize_xml
    tag = elem.tag
AttributeError: 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'tag'
```

This is the latest version of the code I've tried. Can anyone see a solution?

Update:
I have two other ways to convert to the starting JSON file, would one of these be a better approach?

```
import json
import csv

def make_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath):
    data = {}

    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf)

        for rows in csvReader:
            key = rows['Title']
            data[key] = rows

    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf:
        jsonf.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

csvFilePath = r'dataanime.csv'
jsonFilePath = r'dataAnime.json'

make_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath)
```

which errors out my XML conversion when I use this JSON file with it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Data_Int_Final\convert_json_to_xml.py", line 16, in <module>
    et.SubElement(r,"Title").text = d["Title"]
KeyError: 'Title'
```

or:

```
import csv 
import json
import time

def csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath):
    jsonArray = []
      
    #read csv file
    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf: 
        #load csv file data using csv library's dictionary reader
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf) 

        #convert each csv row into python dict
        for row in csvReader: 
            #add this python dict to json array
            jsonArray.append(row)
  
    #convert python jsonArray to JSON String and write to file
    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf: 
        jsonString = json.dumps(jsonArray, indent=4)
        jsonf.write(jsonString)
          
csvFilePath = r'dataanime.csv'
jsonFilePath = r'g_d_anime.json'

start = time.perf_counter()
csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath)
finish = time.perf_counter()
print(f"Conversion of all rows completed successfully in {finish - start:0.4f} seconds")
```

which errors out my XML conversion when I use this created JSON file with it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Data_Int_Final\convert_json_to_xml.py", line 16, in <module>
    et.SubElement(r,"Title").text = d["Title"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Just: `a_xml_str = et.tostring(r)`

Comment: I switched it to `(r)`, it errors out as `TypeError: write() arguement must be str, not dict`.

Comment: You can convert directly from CSV to XML file if that's the desired output. What is the value of intermediate JSON file?

Comment: I'm giving a presentation of how by starting with one file, CSV, you can convert it through multiple formats in a chain. So, CSV to JSON, that JSON to XML, XML to the next file type in the chain, etc, back to CSV.

Comment: In this case the direct conversion of CSV to JSON creates an ugly JSON structure to deal with.

Comment: In that case, to make the JSON file, would any of the updated CSV to JSON code in my question be a better starting point?

Comment: yes that will create a better structed JSON output.

Comment: Put the make_json() in a separate python file and it runs w/o error.

Comment: Each of the files I used to make the JSON file are their own, separate file from the XML conversion file. Creating the JSON isn't my problem at this point, getting any of the JSON files I create to XML is...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239341/discussion-between-codemonkey-and-sassyg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simpler to work with the CSV file and generate a XML file from that directly.

Try something like this:

```python
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

root = et.Element('WorksXML')
tree = et.ElementTree(root)
with open("dataanime.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8") as fin:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fin)
    for row in reader:
        r = et.SubElement(root, "Work")
        # iterate over each of the fields and add to the XML element
        for field in reader.fieldnames:
            et.SubElement(r, field.replace(' ', '_')).text = row[field]

with open("csv_to_xml.xml", 'wb') as fout:
    tree.write(fout, xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8')
```

This generates an XML file with each "work" as a separate sub-element under the root element.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WorksXML>
    <Work>
        <Title>Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood</Title>
        <Type>TV</Type>
        <Episodes>64</Episodes>
        <Status>Finished Airing</Status>
        <Start_airing>4/5/2009</Start_airing>
        <End_airing>7/4/2010</End_airing>
        <Starting_season>Spring</Starting_season>
        ...
```

For the CSV to JSON conversion, the first approach creates a dictionary with titles as keys and the second approach creates an array with each item an object with all the attributes.

If any of the works have a duplicate title then the first approach will overwrite the duplicate entries. If not then it's just a matter of how you want to access the data in the JSON file as a dictionary or a list. If you want to generate XML from the JSON file then the second approach with an array will be the better option.

To convert the array-based JSON file to XML then this will do the job.

```python
import json
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def json_to_xml(jsonFilePath, xmlFilePath):
    root = ET.Element('WorksXML')
    tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
    with open(jsonFilePath, "r", encoding="utf-8") as fin:
        jdata = json.load(fin)
    for obj in jdata:
        r = ET.SubElement(root, "Work")
        for key, value in obj.items():
            ET.SubElement(r, key.replace(' ', '_')).text = value
    with open(xmlFilePath, 'wb') as fout:
        tree.write(fout, xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8')


jsonFilePath = 'g_d_anime.json'
xmlFilePath = 'g_d_anime.xml'

json_to_xml(jsonFilePath, xmlFilePath)
```

Comment: It errors out with `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 3809: character maps to <undefined>`.

Comment: sorry need to add encoding="utf-8" to the open("dataanime.csv",...) line. Updated code above.

Comment: That works, thank you!